# How to delete my @gmail account from GMail client while leaving on Email client?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm have a Samsung S5 which has two (preinstalled, I suppose) email clients, GMail and Email. GMail client has a white envelope with thick red edges icon, while Email has a white envelope with monkey sign in red&white in the middle like a stamp.

Upon setting up my @gmail account and my @company account in the Email client (which is the only one I wish to use) I noticed I started getting notifications from the GMail client as well from my @gmail address. I tried deleting my @gmail account but that deletes it from both email clients.

How can I delete my @gmail account for just one client (GMail) without affecting the other. I originally wanted to just uninstall GMail client but that seems to be impossible since it came preinstalled on the S5, along with a lot of other applications.

Comment: Did you set your Gmail account using the Gmail option, or as a standard pop 3 or imap option?

Comment: @cde - Using the Gmail option I guess; I didn't need to setup anything but login data, as far as I remember.

Comment: *Is there a good reason* for rolling back to revision 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is,  disable notifications for email arrival in your Gmail application and enable notifications for your account in default email app.

I won't recommend disabling the Gmail app because you may want to configure any other email account(s) with your Gmail app and sync mail and other settings to your phone, like contacts and calendar.

Comment: Gmail app has nothing to do with syncing Calendar and Contacts. They are synced very well with Gmail disabled.

Comment: Thanks Alex, for clarifying this. But as we can configure almost all email accounts with a single Gmail app, I personally find it easier and more convenient to use.

Comment: In the end I went with the "turn off notifications option". As much as it is annoying that you can't uninstall software, this solved the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Gmail app. Another option is to turn off syncing email in Gmail: Settings → Accounts & Sync → Google → choose your Google account → uncheck Gmail.